# An anti-symmetric bilinear map $b:V\times V\rightarrow k$ is the difference of two bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

*This seems to be an elementary question, but I could not find an answer in google nor I am able to solve it.*

Let $k$ be any field and let $V$ be a vector space over that field.

A bilinear map $B:V\times V\rightarrow k$ is called anti-symmetric if $b(u,v) = -b(v,u)$ for all $u,v\in V$.

> Prove that any anti-symmetric bilinear form $B$ admits another bilinear form $L$ so that $B(u,v) = L(u,v)-L(v,u)$.

When $k$ is a field of characteristic $\mathrm{char} k\not = 2$, we can take $L:=\frac{B}{2}$ and use anti-symmetry.

When $k=\mathbb{F}_2$ (the field with $2$ elements) and $\dim V = 2$, I computed by hand that if $L=\begin{bmatrix} l_1 & l_2 \\ l_3 & l_4 \end{bmatrix}$, then $L(u,v)-L(v,u) = (l_2-l_3)u_2v_1+(l_3-l_2)u_1v_2$. Another computation shows that any anti-symmetric bilinear map takes this form (Edit: The last claim is apparently wrong unless one assumes in addition that $B(u,u)=0$ for all $u\in V$).

Even a general solution when $k=\mathbb{F}_2$ is appreciated.

Edit: With the additional assumption that $B(u,u)=0$ I can solve the claim for finite dimensional $V$.

Look at the homomorphism $\phi:\mathcal{M}_n(k)\rightarrow \mathcal{M}_n(k)$ which takes an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and sends it to the matrix $\phi(A)$ defined by the form $(u,v)\mapsto u^T A v - v^T Au$.

The kernel of these maps consists of matrices $A$ satisfying $u^TAv = v^TAu$, hence $A=A^T$. This space has dimension $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ (because $A$ is determined by its values on the diagonal and everything above it). Therefore the image has dimension $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$, which is the same as the dimension of anti-symmetric bilinear maps satisfying in addition $B(u,u)=0$ for all $u\in U$.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct definition of anti-symmetric?  There's basically two options: the one you've written and a better one: that $b(u,u)=0$ for all $u\in V$.  The former tends to lead to a lot of errors in characteristic 2.

Comment: @user8675309 Good point. That is probably something I needed to assume

Comment: @Yanko You can always use an upper triangular $L$

Comment: Like set $L(e_i,e_j) = B(e_i,e_j)$ if $i<j$ and zero otherwise? I think it works

Comment: what does the statement *"Edit: With the additional assumption that (,)=0 I can solve the claim for finite dimensional , but still do not know how to do it in general"* mean? Are you contemplating working with infinite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb F_2$?  You'll need to explain how the convergence criterion works and why this is still an "elementary" question.

Comment: @user8675309 No its ok, I am satisfied with the answer as is. But yes you're right I needed to be more concrete for the infinite dimensional case. Thank you anyway, your comment was useful to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result does not hold over fields with characteristic $2$.

It is not even true that every anti-symmetric bilinear map $\Bbb F_2^2$ takes the form you suggested. For instance, note that the bilinear map
$$
b(v,u) = u_1v_1 + u_2v_2
$$
Is **antisymmetric** (in addition to being symmetric) over $\Bbb F_2$. Indeed, note that $x = -x$ for $x \in \Bbb F^2$, which means that $b(u,v) = b(v,u) \iff b(u,v) = -b(v,u)$.

Comment: Right! I see... Do you know whether adding the condition "$b(u,u)=0$ for all $u\in V$" leads to the desired conclusion? (In other words, is your counterexample the "only" counterexample)

Comment: @Yanko I’m not sure

Comment: Thank you. I have added a (non-constructive) proof for finite dimensional vector spaces.